# How can I repair a towel bar with one end ripped out of the wall?

Tags: repair, bathroom, shower, bathroom-fixtures

I'm in desperate need of assistance. I'm a tenant living in a rented apartment and one end of the towel bar just fell out of its socket!

Can anyone tell me how, if possible, I can fix it myself without telling my landlord? Or in the worst case scenario that I have to call someone, can you tell me who I should call?

I'm sorry but I'm new to all of this so I don't even know who to call to come fix it if I can't fix it myself. You are supposed to call an electrician for electrical stuff and a plumber for your plumbing but who should you call for something like this? Any help would be truly appreciated.

If it is possible to fix it myself, could you help by giving me detailed instructions on how to do so including any materials I might need to buy. I've attached pictures since I don't know how to describe it like what screws it uses and such.

*Click any photo for full size*

[image: pic of towel rack 2]
[image: pic of towel rack 3]

[image: pic of towel rack 4]
[image: pic of towel rack 5]

[image: pic of towel rack 6]
[image: pic of towel rack 8]

[image: pic of towel rack 9]
[image: pic of towel rack 10]

Comment: Nice clear pictures!

Answer (score 6):

I agree that the best solution here is tell your landlord, provided you have a reasonable one. What does your lease say about routine maintenance? Chances are if you weren't doing chinups on it, you shouldn't be charged.

However, if you've had a previous experience with this landlord in which they've proved to be unreasonable, you could attempt to fix it yourself.

To do this, find a short length of steel rod with an outer diameter the same as the inside diameter of the sheared pin. Test fit to make sure it all fits together. Mix up some JB Weld, coat the steel rod, and then slide it into the sleeve on the wall, then press the other side on over it. Try to avoid getting any of the epoxy compound on the end of the rod near the wall, as doing so may end up bonding it to the wall rather than just the bracket.

Comment: Keep in mind many a landlord would rather be told, than have a bad DIY repair made.  I'd rather be told, than have a tenant make an amateur repair that may fail if a future tenant grabs the bar to arrest a fall.

Comment: This is a good idea on how to fix this broken bracket. I would like to suggest that it may be a good idea to first remove the bracket shoulder from the wall and pre-glue (with the JB-Weld) the metal rod into the shoulder piece. Then as a second step glue the shoulder back onto the towel rack bar. Note that it is possible that there may be a small set screw from the under side of the towel bar rack bar that permits removing the broken off shaft from inside the chrome bar piece. If so it will be way easier to glue up with these pieces free unto themselves.

Comment: Excellent suggestion, @MichaelKaras.

Comment: @Bryce: It's a towel bar, not a handrail specifically designed to arrest falls. For the intended purpose, the "DIY fix" I suggested should be every bit as strong, if not stronger than the original hardware, which has already failed.

Comment: The type of break makes me think the metal bar in there was just brittle pot metal. Depending on the type of bar used in the repair, the shoulder area of that towel rack could indeed wind up stronger than it was before.

Comment: Yes it is clearly pot metal.  The shaft approach is a good repair, if done well. The point stands that it's the landlord's prerogative to choose the type and nature of repair.  The landlord is on the hook if this repair ever injures someone. @Doresoom.  Given the the position of the bar on the tile, it may be used as a grab bar: perhaps that's even why it broke.

Answer (score 3):

Sad to say, the pot-metal piece attached to the wall broke, and it's likely hard to find the right replacement part.

The proper person to call in a case like this is your landlord.  If it broke without unreasonable force, you should not be charged.  The landlord owns the property and has the right to choose the time and manner of repair (she/he may not want a first timer to make the repair, for example).  Your landlord may have a stock of the exact towel bar and thus have factory new parts.

Else the proper profession is '*handyman*'.

An epoxy repair is possible here, but is tricky and may not hold. This answer from @Doresoom gives an excellent method to make such a repair: https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/40608/5960

Answer (score 2):

Honestly?  The easiest fix is to replace the whole towel rail, at your own cost.  The only tools you'll need is a large Phillips screwdriver, and perhaps some cleaning products for the wall.

The only critical measurement is the overall length.  So take the old one off the wall, and go visit a hardware store.  The US has Lowes or Home Depot or Walmart or similar, and most other countries will have similar large shops with many aisles.

Buying online from the likes of Amazon or ebay tends to be a bit riskier, because you can't visually check its what you need beforehand.

In the store, hold the old one up to the new rail through the packaging, and confirm the length is identical.  Ideally, the mountings would be the same design too, so you can reuse the same mounting holes and screws.

Visually, any similar design and chromed towel rail will be hard to notice.

You may choose to store the old towel rail or recycle/bin it.

Comment: I'm I favor of this answer.  You may be responsible for repairs under some amount, maybe $50.  A new double rail is about $40.  A tube of epoxy weld is $15 and unlikely to stand up to someone yanking a towel off.